# Install Ubuntu to a preformatted partition

Tags: installation

I tried to install Ubuntu from a USB stick but I got confused when it started to install on my external USB drive. What I want to do is use an existing partition on one of my 2 1TB Hard drives which has already been partitioned.

Can you help please?

Answer (score 0):

In the ubuntu installer, choose the `choose something else` option when you are asked where ubuntu should be installed. (other than this option, there will be options like erase previous OS, install alongside etc.) You will be presented with a list of all partitions to which you can install ubuntu. If you dont know what device (/dev/sdxn) your partition corresponds to open it in nautilus (unmount everything else from the nautlius side pane) man run `mount` from the terminal to find the device.